# How to make css columns wrap around a cutout

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: newspaper]

I would like to make a layout like the one above.  How can I make the column wrap around the image box?  I need it to be able to span across several columns if that is possible.  I have tried this for weeks to no avail.

I tried flexbox, and that may be a good solution, but I have yet to make it work.

Is there a simple way that this could be done?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Float didn't work when I spanned multiple columns.

Comment: yeah html/css wasn't really designed with horizontal newspaper layouts in mind, so this isn't going to be easy unless you want to constrain the image to one column.

Comment: If you can drop your layout into a jsfiddle I could probably do something with jquery to make it happen though.

Comment: What about vanilla JS?  I don't do JQuery yet.

Comment: http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/    this is a jquery plugin that might help you with what you are trying to do. but remember if you are creating a page which has to be ADA/508 compliant then this  plugin may not be for you as the image is not recognized by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested using of a jquery plugin called jQslickWrap to achieve the effect that OP wanted. But if using jquery or javascript is not wanted, we can try to do the plain css way.

Now OP wants a newspaper style look to the page. So I propose a larger container div within which would be a number of smaller column divs ( i have used 4 for my example) all floated left and styled as needed.

Now here goes the code...

```css
#container{
    height:600px;
    width:80%;
    background:#cecece;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#col1,#col2, #col3, #col4 {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
 padding: 2px 5px;
}
#col1{
    background-color:#ad2340;
}
#col2{
    background-color:#3d2ed4;
}
#col3{
    background-color:#f2234b;
}
#col4{
    background-color:#aa3340;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="col1">
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x120/000/fff.png"/>
  <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
  <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum bla.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
  <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum bla.</p>
        
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p><p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum bla.</p>
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col4">
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah lrem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps